Getting io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception Channel Pipeline: exception
I recently started working on BigTable to ingest/ read the data to it
Since it is a POC I am using free GCP account.
I have enabled cloud bigtable api and to my service account have added all the required roles like big data viewer/reader/administrater et cetra.
But still when I tried to ingest the data using data client. Below is the ingestion code I am using to ingest to big table
I am using spring boot with java 17 app to ingest the data to big table and given GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS as an environment variable with the service account(added all the big table roles to it) json as value in intelliJ IDE tool
            long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() * 1000;
            String rowkey = "r1";
            RowMutation rowMutation = RowMutation.create(TABLE_NAME, rowkey);
            rowMutation.setCell(
                    COLUMN_FAMILY_NAME,
                    ByteString.copyFrom("connected_cell".getBytes()),
                    timestamp,
                    1L);
            bigtableDataClient.mutateRow(rowMutation);
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Successfully wrote row with key "+rowkey);

I am getting the below error when i tried to ingest the data from this call- bigtableDataClient.mutateRow(rowMutation), here is the  exception trace.
: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]

com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnavailableException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:112) ~[gax-2.35.0.jar:2.35.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:41) ~[gax-2.35.0.jar:2.35.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:86) ~[gax-grpc-2.35.0.jar:2.35.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:66) ~[gax-grpc-2.35.0.jar:2.35.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97) ~[gax-grpc-2.35.0.jar:2.35.0]
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:84) ~[api-common-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1127) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:31) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1286) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.addListener(AbstractFuture.java:760) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingListenableFuture.addListener(ForwardingListenableFuture.java:45) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutureToListenableFuture.addListener(ApiFutureToListenableFuture.java:49) ~[api-common-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures.addCallback(Futures.java:1100) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures.addCallback(ApiFutures.java:79) ~[api-common-2.18.0.jar:2.18.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable.futureCall(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:67) ~[gax-grpc-2.35.0.jar:2.35.0]
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.stub.metrics.StatsHeadersUnaryCallable.futureCall(StatsHeadersUnaryCallable.java:41) ~[google-cloud-bigtable-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
    at com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.stub.metrics.BigtableTracerUnaryCallable.futureCall(BigtableTracerUnaryCallable.java:62) ~[google-cloud-bigtable-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.rpc.AttemptCallable.call(AttemptCallable.java:87) ~[gax-2.35.0.jar:2.35.0]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:131) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:75) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:82) ~[guava-32.1.2-jre.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57) ~[gax-2.35.0.jar:2.35.0]
        at com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2.BigtableDataClient.mutateRow(BigtableDataClient.java:964) ~[google-cloud-bigtable-2.28.0.jar:2.28.0]
        at com.re.bigtable.controller.impl.ProfileControllerImpl.insert(ProfileControllerImpl.java:61) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:255) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:926) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:831) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:6.0]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885) ~[spring-webmvc-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:6.0]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.1.6.jar:6.1.6]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:175) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.20.jar:10.1.20]
        ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:537) ~[grpc-api-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:538) ~[grpc-stub-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39) ~[grpc-api-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23) ~[grpc-api-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40) ~[grpc-api-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool$ReleasingClientCall$1.onClose(ChannelPool.java:546) ~[gax-grpc-2.35.0.jar:2.35.0]
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39) ~[grpc-api-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23) ~[grpc-api-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40) ~[grpc-api-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcMetadataHandlerInterceptor$1$1.onClose(GrpcMetadataHandlerInterceptor.java:76) ~[gax-grpc-2.35.0.jar:2.35.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:567) ~[grpc-core-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:71) ~[grpc-core-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:735) ~[grpc-core-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:716) ~[grpc-core-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) ~[grpc-core-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133) ~[grpc-core-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.handshakeException(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1929) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.wrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:836) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap(SslHandler.java:1042) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapNonAppData(SslHandler.java:928) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1419) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrapNonAppData(SslHandler.java:1337) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.access$1800(SslHandler.java:170) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslTasksRunner.resumeOnEventExecutor(SslHandler.java:1728) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslTasksRunner.access$2000(SslHandler.java:1619) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslTasksRunner$2.run(SslHandler.java:1780) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:439) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:306) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:285) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144) ~[na:na]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext$ExtendedTrustManagerVerifyCallback.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext.java:234) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext$AbstractCertificateVerifier.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:785) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.internal.tcnative.CertificateVerifierTask.runTask(CertificateVerifierTask.java:36) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSLTask.run(SSLTask.java:48) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSLTask.run(SSLTask.java:42) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.runAndResetNeedTask(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1518) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.access$700(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:94) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine$TaskDecorator.run(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1493) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslTasksRunner.run(SslHandler.java:1797) ~[grpc-netty-shaded-1.58.0.jar:1.58.0]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    ... 1 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:434) ~[na:na]
    ... 16 common frames omitted

Got stuck on this issue for a while tried to play with the GCP account  by adding required API's /roles but not yeilding any results. Any of your help is highly appreciated.
At first was in an assumption that it is because of cert issue while connecting to gcp cloud and imported gcp cert to my dev machine and added it to cacerts of my jdk.
From console CLI using cbt commands, I can able to create table and insert the data to that table under few column families with out any issues.
But when I tried to ingest few cells of data to that table through springboot rest app, for validating the insertion it is ending up in above issue. Tried to play with the GCP account by adding required API's /roles.
Still it didn't solved the issue.
Any of your help is highly appreciated.

It's good practice to provide a minimal repro of your issue so that we may better understand what you've done. You say you're using "free GCP account" but -- IIUC -- Bigtable has no free tier so you will be unable to use it unless you have established billing. The StatusRuntimeException could be simply Bigtable enforcing that requirement. Please consider updating your question with specific details of what you've done. Have you tried using the cbt CLI to interact with your Bigtable instance?

@DazWilkin -  Thanks for the response. Yes I can able to perform Create, Read and delete operations on my big table table through cbt CLI. The above mentioned issue happening only when I tried to insert some sample real time data to big table using spring-boot app. Since I am new this GCP couldn't able to figure out the issue. I observed few of them ingested data with GCP free basic account with 300$ added to it by Google. Let me know if you require any information to dig more on this issue and to help me out.
